# Java 8 Stream groupingby

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have `List<Map<String, String>>` each item in the list is a map e.g

```
companyName - IBM
firstName - James
country - USA
...
```

I would like create a `Map<String, List<String>>` where it maps companyName to a list of of firstName
e.g

```
IBM -> James, Mark
ATT -> Henry, Robert..


private Map<String,List<String>> groupByCompanyName(List<Map<String, String>> list) {
    return list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(item->item.get("companyName")));
}
```

but this will create `Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>` (mapping comanyName to a list of maps)

how to create a `Map<String, List<String>>`?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Haven't tested it, but something like this should work:

```
Map<String, List<String>> namesByCompany
    = list.stream()
          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(item->item.get("companyName"),
                   Collectors.mapping(item->item.get("firstName"), Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: Is there any way to get `String[]` instead of `List<String>`

Comment: I don't think so (at least not directly), since there's no `Collectors.toArray` method. @VinitSolanki

Answer (score 5):

You can use the form:

```
groupingBy(Function<? super T,? extends K> classifier, Collector<? super T,A,D> downstream)
```

i.e. specify the values from the map in the downstream to be taken as list. The documentation has good example for it ([here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-)).

`downstream` being something like - `mapping(item->item.get(<name>), toList())`

Answer (score 0):

The groupingBy method yields a map whose values are lists. If you want to process those lists in some way, supply a "downstream collector"
In you case, you don't want a List as the value, so you need to provide a downstream collector.

To manipulate the Map, you can use the static method mapping in Collectors file:

```
Collector<T, ?, R> mapping(Function<? super T, ? extends U> mapper,
                           Collector<? super U, A, R> downstream)
```

It basically generates a collector by applying a function to the downstream results and passes the function to another collector.

```
Collectors.mapping(item->item.get("firstName"), Collectors.toList())
```

This will return a downstream collector which will achieve what you want.